# Malformed HTML in a OSX Webview

Tags: html, macos, webview, parse-error

Is it possible to detect parse errors in an HTML submitted to a WebView, using `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:`?

Is there a method that can be called when parsing errors occur?

Answer (score 1):

The only possible delegate callback might be [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Webkit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidFailLoadWithError%3aforFrame%3a), but I don't think it will give you what you're looking for (it's almost certainly network errors). A quick perusal through [the list of possible NSError codes](http://nshipster.com/nserror/) (near the bottom), don't have anything that might relate to your error. It seems you're out of luck here.

If you need to deal with parsing, then you're going to be using a different HTML renderer, such as WebKit or Blink. There are a few frameworks for building native apps that use the WebKit or Blink renderer. One of the most active is called [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). While I can't say for absolute certainty that it will expose the parsing that you're looking for, the odds are much higher.

Some others that are similar are [appJS](http://appjs.com/) and [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). I like Node-Webkit because it's very simple to set up while also being fairly mature and in rapid development. If it doesn't give you what you're looking for, one of those others might.

Comment: That's the one I tried but it's for low level network errors I think. Does this mean that I have to use a third-party parser or the one Webkit is using ? Meaning parsing the HTML twice..

Comment: If you don't want to use the built in WebView class, an outside renderer is likely your only recourse here.

Comment: Wouln't it make more sense to make some modifications in Webkit to expose a part of the HTML tree builder ? I'm not saying it's easy.. but isn't WebView compiled from Webkit ? I found an article where the author explains how to overlay the CSS bounding boxes. http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/02/05/a-visual-method-for-understanding-webkit-layout/ That's not really related, but it's a starting point..

Comment: WebView does use WebKit underneath, I was including using WebKit directly as an "outside renderer" though, since you're not using the API built into WebView. If that's the road you want to go down, you can go for it, it's going to be very difficult though. You may want to look into something like Node-Webkit for your app instead.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille I know it wasn't the answer you're looking for, but I would be appreciative for the check.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more in your answer on outside renderer and Node-Webkit ?

Comment: Edited the answer to give more details on possible alternative solutions.